# send email using RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sendmail

I followed *[THIS](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html)* site on how to send an email using RoR. After running the server and calling the method, it shows in the console:

```
Rendered user_mailer/welcome_email.html.erb (1.0ms)
Rendered user_mailer/welcome_email.text.erb (1.0ms)

Sent mail to neeraj.narang11@gmail.com (1128ms)
Date: Sun, 18 Sep 2011 13:44:49 +0530

From: from@example.com

To: neeraj.narang11@gmail.com

Message-ID: <4e75a87912b3b_ed81feda64668f4@Narang-PC.mail>

Subject: Welcome to My Awesome Site

Mime-Version: 1.0

Content-Type: multipart/alternative;

 boundary="--==_mimepart_4e75a878df4a2_ed81feda646659d";

 charset=UTF-8

Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
.......
```

but I'm not getting any email in my inbox. Could someone please tell me what's the issue here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you haven't:

```
config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
```

in your development.rb file.

Comment: thanks apneadiving...but now i'm getting an error: `Errno::ECONNREFUSED (No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. - connect(2)):` on the line in the controller on which i call `deliver`. Could u please tell me any solution for this...

Comment: I'm calling the deliver method in my login controller. I call the deliver method as follows: `UserMailer.welcome_email(user).deliver`. If I call the deliver method, I get the error: `Errno::ECONNREFUSED (No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. - connect(2)): app/controllers/login_controller.rb:16:in login`, but if i comment it, then the login succeeds as required.

Answer (score 1):

Some time ago i`ve played around with [Ryan screencast on Action Mailer](http://railscasts.com/episodes/206-action-mailer-in-rails-3) and everything went just fine. Check it out!

Comment: that page tells us how to use gmail SMTP server to send mail right? I'm running the application on local server deployed on WEBrick. The example that I mentioned in the post doesn't mention anything about configuring the ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings...

Comment: i put the following settings in my environment.rb file: `ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
  :address => "smtp.gmail.com",
  :port => 587,
  :authentication => :login,
  :user_name => "my gmail username",
  :password => "my gmail pwd"
}
ActionMailer::Base.delivery_method = :smtp` & it worked. But can we do it without using gmail SMTP server to send mail?